Undefined resource 'archive' after installing `puppet-archive`
After installing the puppet-archive module via r10k, Puppet does not recognize the resource, despite seemingly correctly including it, and throws the following error:
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER:
  Server Error: Evaluation Error:
  Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'archive'
    (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/repro_issue/modules/role/manifests/archive_issue/archive_issue.pp, line: 4, column: 6)
    on node MY_NODE

On the server, however, I can see things look correct:
$ puppet module list --environment repro_issue | grep "archive"
├── puppet-archive (v7.1.0)
$ puppet config print modulepath --environment repro_issue
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/repro_issue/modules


Puppetfile
mod 'puppet-archive', '7.1.0'
mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib', '9.6.0'

Node Definition
node /MY_NODE/ {
  include role::archive_issue::archive_issue
}

Role Contents
#
class role::archive_issue::archive_issue {
  include 'archive'
  -> archive { 'C:\\nginx-1.27.0.zip':
    ensure       => present,
    source       => 'https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.27.0.zip',
    extract_path => 'C:\\',
  }
}

What am I missing? We have other modules that work correctly (puppetlabs-apache, puppetlabs-python, puppetlabs-apt) -- it just seems to be the addition of new modules that doesn't work.

This issue is caused by missing resource types on the server, and can be fixed manually by running puppet generate types --environment $ENVIRONMENT.
When deploying via r10k, the process may be automated by adding a post-run action that generates types for all modified environments, as documented in the r10k FAQ.
